# I have problem with receieving POST type http requests

Tags: python, django, http, post, httprequest

So... My issue is very simple.

I send request from my roblox game using http request (POST method). Now... I've tested with php already, the request is sent successfully and is receieved. However, we talk about Django here.

I really want to do that on Django, because I am more familliar with python + I want to do a lot of complicated things, and I highly believe Django is simply what I need

With my problem, I suspect simple problem, such as not adding few lines, or simply wrong instalation of django or something else (even tho am very sure I did that correctly)

Anyways, if that isn't clear, I send a POST request into the .py file which is placed on my website.
The website does not run on my PC, but on my paid VPS which runs on linux ubuntu.

After the request is sent, the script is supposed to get the request, and at least tell me it's receieved in my logs, which works perfectly fine.

Script:

```
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="testfile", filemode="w",
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body)
        # Now I should access the data in post_data dictionary
        logging.debug(post_data)
        return HttpResponse('Received POST request.')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        get_data = request.GET.dict()
        #Now I should access the data in get_data dictionary
        logging.debug(get_data)
        return HttpResponse('Received GET request.')

for i in range(6):
    logging.debug("Process working")
    time.sleep(5)

#logging.debug("Works?")
#logging.info()
#logging.warning()
#logging.error()
#logging.critical()
```

I have tried using pm2 to try make the script run all the time. But am not sure if it goes online because I may lack something, most important I get in my logs file "Process working" message, but not (post_data)

Sending here roblox script is pointless cuz it works 100%, either I may have issues related to not having something on my VPS, or having it in wrong place or such. Or the script simply doesn't work.

My goal here is to simply get the data from roblox game, into VPS. This can be used to for instance to log when someone joins the game and such. I will carry the rest of the script once I'll be able to receieve data.

I really need to get that on VPS due I have my discord bot on it, and stuff like that. I just simply can't do the things that I want to do in roblox game.

Feel free to inform me if you have any questions relating this post. I am really help desperate.

Comment: You are missing a `#` at `Now I should access the data...` which seems to be a comment

Comment: @LMC Thanks for reporting the issue, however the # is in place in the actual script, somehow deleted that when making the post.

Comment: Your suggestion on PHP makes me think you are expecting it to work like a PHP file on the webserver but it will not. Your `home` function looks valid if not look into the details, 
but it's not obvious if you have set up a URL for it, and started django the right way.  Try to take a look at manage.py runserver command, and if it will resolve your issue then take a look at deployment section of documentation.

Comment: Why aren't you using `request.POST` to retrieve the POST data instead of `json.loads(request.body)` ?

Comment: Also, have you tried without the `for i in range(6):` block? Why would you need that anyway ? The `time.sleep()` may be problematic.

Comment: @Zatigem The issue must be made by variuable. I have found something like this:
www-data 22197 22196  0 Nov10 ?        00:00:42 /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py {userID:123456789}

The userID is the information sent from the roblox.

I've found it in PIDs.